# Python RSA модуль pycrypto конвертировать зашифрованные данные в строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa

Всем привет. У меня проблема с модулем pycrypto, я не знаю как конвертировать зашифрованные данные RSA ключём в строку, записать в файл, потом прочитать из файла и расшифровать.
Этот код просто шифрует строку и расшифровывает, а мне нужно конвертировать зашифрованные данные в строку и обратно.

```
with open('pubkey.pem', 'rb') as f:
        pubKey = f.read()
msg = b'A message for encryption'
importedpk = RSA.importKey(pubKey)
encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(importedpk)
encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(msg)

with open('privkey.pem', 'r') as f:
    privKey = f.read()
k = RSA.importKey(privKey)
decryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(k)
decrypted = decryptor.decrypt(encrypted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему, нужно просто использовать модуль pickle